# Download a file in pdf/doc/txt in jsf

Tags: jsf, pdf, download

I am new to jsf and I have a project in which a user has an option of giving a link and extracting the data from that link and saving it in a string. I did this part, but now I want the saved string to be converted into a PDF or Word or text document, and the user must able to download that document. What is the easy way to do this?

EG:

String s=WebGet.getURLData(o.getLink());.

The above step in the code shows the step of saving the content of the given link. Now I want the content in the string as a document  (which can be a PDF/Word/text). I want the string to be the content of the file, and the user must be able to download it.

Comment: NEED SOME HELP @BalusC

Comment: `@Nickname` comment-reply-notifications don't work if the person in question hasn't commented on the very same post before. SHOUTING also don't have any positive effect, not only because I'm deaf, but also because it's according the netiquette interpreted as being rude and disrespectful.

Comment: Sorry @Balusc But to my knowledge i never replied in a rude way..But my english is so bad that i can not express what i mean in a good way!!Probably thats where it went wrong!! Anyway Sorry!!


And thanks to the person who suggested edits in my post!!